# how to get height width of a stackpanel (with invisible scrolled area)

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

i am trying to take a snapshot of my screen in a wpf application. everything works fine, but the only problem is that, when i need to take the screenshot of the contents of a stakpanel which have some hidden contents in a scrollviewer's scrolled area, my code only takes a snaphsot of the visible part of stackpanel. plz take a look below...

RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
                      new RenderTargetBitmap(
                        (int)spMain.ActualWidth,
                        (int)spMain.ActualHeight,
                        70d,
                        70d,
                        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

ActualWidth/ActualHeight properties only provide the height/width of the visible part.

Q- how can i get a snapshot of the complete stackpanel?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by measuring and arranging the UI Element before taking the snapshot.

spMain.Measure(new Size(spMain.ActualWidth, spMain.ActualHeight));
spMain.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(spMain.ActualWidth, spMain.ActualHeight)));

:)